# The website encountered an unexpected error due to installing custom module

Tags: navigation

I have created and installed custom module without additional code[with mymodule.info and mymodule.module].But after I created

> mymodule.links.menu.yml and mymodule.routing.yml i am grtting error like "The website encountered an unexpected error" code mymodule.links.menu.yml

```
   mymodule.admin_form
     title: Upload IELTS Test Dates
     parent: cedar.admin_index
     weight: 100
     route_name : mymodule.admin_form
```

and code inside mymodule.routing.yml

```
 mymodule.settings:
   path: '/admin/config/services/migs'
   defaults:
     _controller: '\Drupal\quotesapi\Controller\MymoduleController::settings'
     _title: 'My module settings'
   requirements:
     _permission: 'administer site configuration'
```

I checked the watchdog and found a `RouteNotFoundException`. How do I fix this?

Comment: It’s not possible to debug a site without access to it - once you’ve checked your server and Drupal’s error logs, and done further research on the error messages that you find there, if you still have a specific question about your code, please ask a question containing full details of the error, and a snippet of code that can be used to reproduce it. Many thanks

Comment: Can I get my site, if I comment those code in mymodule.links.menu.yml and mymodule.routing.yml ? I don't need that module.

Comment: If that's what's causing the problem, I'd imagine that will work, yes. You'll probably need to clear caches

Comment: I have updated my question.Now I couldn't see admin pages.It's showing the unexpected error for all pages.So my question is can I get my site back after commenting those code?

Comment: It's impossible to say from here - try it and see what happens. If the links/routing file are invalid in some way then commenting them out or removing them entirely, followed by a cache rebuild, should be enough to fix it. If it doesn't, you need to find out what the error is by looking in the watchdog (/admin/reports/dblog). If you can't get to that page, look at the most recent entry in the `watchdog` table in the database with type `php`, a combination of the `message` and `variables` column will get you the real error message

Comment: Thanks . I have search watchdog, it's blob file and I found out "RouteNotFoundException".What will be the solution ?

Comment: No problem, that little bit of debugging makes all the difference, it should be a straight forward fix (I put an answer in). I'll clear these comments up in a bit as the relevant info is in the question now

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a simple naming error. Your route name in the links file is:

```
route_name : mymodule.admin_form
```

But in your routing.yml you have:

```
 mymodule.settings:
```

Update one or the other so they both match, clear the cache, and it should work.

Comment: How can I clear cache without getting admin page ?Is it by clearing cache tables?

Comment: I have added missing route name and clear the cache.But it still showing the same in watchdog.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
mymodule.admin_form
```

By

```
mymodule.admin_form:
```

Change:

```
route_name : mymodule.admin_form
```

By

```
route_name : mymodule.settings
```

**Note**: check the [official documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/add-a-menu-link): on this page, there is an example of the use of the file: `links.menu.yml`. The file name must end in ":". and in the `route_name` parameter you must refer to the name of the route that is in the `routing.yml` file.